# Set Alert to Pop when App first Opens/Let User Set in App Password

Tags: ios, objective-c, uialertview

Cannot get the alerts to pop when a user first opens the app. I want different alerts on each view to guide the user through their first run.

I cannot figure out what I am missing. Have looked through various posts on the site and cannot figure it out.

ViewController.h

```
    #import <UIKit/UIKit.h>



@interface ViewController : UIViewController <UINavigationControllerDelegate,UIImagePickerControllerDelegate> {

}

@end
```

ViewController.m

```
#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end



@implementation ViewController


- (void)viewdDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
}
- (BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions {

    if(![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"AlreadyRan"] )
    {
        UIAlertController * alert=   [UIAlertController
                                      alertControllerWithTitle:@"The Key"
                                      message:@"Press The Key Hole"
                                      preferredStyle:UIAlertControllerStyleAlert];

        UIAlertAction* ok = [UIAlertAction
                             actionWithTitle:@"OK"
                             style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                             handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                             {
                                 [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                             }];
        UIAlertAction* cancel = [UIAlertAction
                                 actionWithTitle:@"Cancel"
                                 style:UIAlertActionStyleDefault
                                 handler:^(UIAlertAction * action)
                                 {
                                     [alert dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion:nil];

                                 }];

        [alert addAction:ok];
        [alert addAction:cancel];

        [self presentViewController:alert animated:YES completion:nil];

        [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:TRUE forKey:@"AlreadyRan"];
    }
    return 0;
}



@end
```

Also on another view controller I want the user to be able to set the password via an alert popup as well the first time the app is ran. Here is the code where I have the password set to a standard password. The password doesn't need to be store to a keychain, it isn't that kind of app I just want the app to save it locally.

PassViewController.m

```
- (IBAction)enterPassword {
    NSString *passwordString = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"1234"];

    if ([passwordField.text isEqualToString:passwordString]) {
        //Password is Correct
        NSString * storyboardName = @"Main";
        UIStoryboard *storyboard = [UIStoryboard storyboardWithName:storyboardName bundle: nil];
        UIViewController * vc = [storyboard instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"PhotoView"];
        [self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];

    }


    else {
        //Password is wrong
        [self dismissViewControllerAnimated:YES completion: nil];

}
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've implemented `(BOOL)application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions` inside your view controller, but actually this method belongs to the `UIApplicationDelegate` protocol (usually located in your AppDelegate.m).

So iOS will never call this method.

I think what you're looking for is `-(void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated { ... }`. That gets invoked when the view controller comes on screen. So your implementation looks like

```
-(void) viewDidAppear: (BOOL) animated {
    [super viewDidAppear: animated];
    /* All your other code that used to be in didFinishLaunchingWithOptions */
}
```

Comment: That worked. Thank you very much!! Do you happen to know how to allow the user to edit the password?